# how to build vp8 codec for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, codec, vp8

i have downloaded vp8 codec  code from android.git.kernel.org. I am facing dificulties on compiling vp8 code for android.

Any one kindly guide me how to build vp8 codec step by step to create a so file.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to build it? I'm currently building vp8 (libvpx library) as part of getting WebRTC to run on Android. I'm included modified version of Android.mk file that's in <android_source>/external/libvpx/Android.mk (just really to normalize the paths).

Comment: this link maybe could help you,he has the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634392/build-vp8-on-android